# Kivy (Python) problems with reassigning "source" property

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I have a class with the method, that changes the image of ImageButton when *on_press* and *on_release*.

It looks like that and it works:

```
class MainMenu(Screen):
    def new_game_button_press(self):
    self.ids.new_game_button.source = "img/ui/new_game_press.png"

    def new_game_button_release(self):
    self.ids.new_game_button.source = "img/ui/new_game.png"
```

*I wanted* to rewrite it into the kivy (.kv) file just for clarity and to avoid repetition in the .py file itself.

Here is my .kv file:

```
<MainMenu>
name: "MainMenu"

FloatLayout:
    size: root.width, root.height

    CoverImage:
        source: "img/fgo_wl.png"

    ImageButton:
        id: new_game_button
        source: "img/ui/new_game_hover.png" if self.hovered else "img/ui/new_game.png"
        pos_hint:{'x': .77, 'y': .65}
        size_hint:(.25, .115)

        allow_stretch: True
        keep_ratio: True
        mipmap: True

        on_press:
        # root.new_game_button_press()
        source: "img/ui/new_game_press.png"
        on_release:
        source: "img/ui/new_game.png"
        # root.new_game_button_release()
```

So, my problem is when I am reassigning the ImageButton "source property", actually my image of Button **image doesn't change**... (indentation in kivy code example during copy-paste to this post was broken, don't pay attention)

```
on_press:
    source: "img/ui/new_game_press.png"
 on_release:
    source: "img/ui/new_game.png"
```

Is there a way to solve this problem in Kivy's way (or it's just my impracticable wish)?

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) addressing your main problem.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what ur trying to do with that imageButton but here is a simpler and efficient way:

**kv File**

```
Button:
     size:
     pos:
     ###:
     on_press: root.press()
     on_release: root.rlease()       
     Image:
         id: btn_image
         source: ''  ##### set ur initial image
```

**in kivy**

```
def press(self):
    self.ids.btn_image.source = 'what u need.png'

def rlease(self):
    self.ids.btn_image.source = 'changed.png'
```